# Service to use a VPN through PHP

Tags: php, networking, ip, vpn

I'm looking to crawl different URLs from different countries programatically through PHP so I can record where they go. This will be to check to make sure the links really go to where they should go to. (Not a dead link, ect.) The URL will automatically route me elsewhere if the specified country doesn't match so I'm looking for a VPN service with multiple countries that accepts requests from PHP. Something I can send simple requests to visit a URL and just tell me back the URLs it jumped through to get there and which URL it ended on.

I understand PHP doesn't care what IP I'm on but maybe there is a service out there that does this. Can anyone point me in the right direction of a service that works like that or maybe have a better solution for doing this? It can't be  manual solution. It must be something that can work with code automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to use any VPN service offering SOCKS-proxies or OpenVPN. Both options are well documеnted and don't require extraordinary skills or privileges to run.
Usually those services offer tons of ready to use configuration files, so you'll be able to easily switch exit gateway countries from your scripts.
The largest VPN provider is hidemyass.com, the list of alternatives you can google or find here: https://vpntips.com/hidemyass-alternatives/
Another option is to use TOR network and choose exit countries. Yes, it has such option: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit .
But TOR is usually overloaded and will give you many false failures, timeouts and a full range of other connectivity troubles.